# Is it correct to retrieve Model data in a View, or just in the Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, architecture, design-patterns

I have an MVC application and I typically have the controller pass everything needed by the view.  But when my views are nested inside of other views it's a pain to have to forward these variables on to the nested view.

Is that just how it is, or should I allow my partials/fragments nested inside my views retrieve data from the Model?

As an example, I have a list of states that I use in several nested partials/fragments.  I have to pass this list through my views every time I want to use them only on nested partials/fragments in those views.  Seems like it's prone to error and it feels not very DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly valid for View to directly read from the Model.

Look at wikipedia article or at a picture by Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html

Comment: Martin Fowler is Design Pattern Guru, but you may have missed a key piece of this diagram. Note the arrows between View and Model are not bi-directional. i.e. the View can *write* to the Model but not *read* from it.

Comment: This means Model shouldn't has an access to the View.

Comment: An another link where Martin describes MVC in more detail: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Comment: I appreciate the clarification and value the links. It's still not something I would personally do, but respect it is a valid approach.

Answer (score 3):

The View should *never* have *direct* access to the Model. In fact, the whole point of the MVC paradigm is that each component is loosely coupled with the other. So you can swap our your Models or Views easily. You can't do that if you put Model code in your View.

Helpers or other modules tend to ease the pain in these situations. I would suggest looking into those. There is also the concept of "Fat Models, Skinny Controllers", putting more in your Model so it is easier to access data shared across multiple Controllers.

In the end, it's up to you. MVC lines can get blurred. However, IMO, accessing the Model directly from the View violates the core concepts.

Comment: I've seen various implementations of View Helpers before but how in this case would you suggest they be used?  I don't see how allowing the view to read from a View Helper is any different than allowing it to read from the Model directly.  What is its purpose?  Is it just a way to wrap around the Model and expose only the non-destructive methods of the Model?

Comment: By your example, a view helper could return the data/markup for your `state` lists. The encapsulation provided by the Helper is the point. However, View Helpers, typically don't access the model directly either. So if you truly do have a `State` Model, then passing it from the Controller, however tedious, is the *right* way to do it IMO. I welcome other feedback though.

Comment: You've described something like the Passive View pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). It is indeed a variation of MVC but it is far less common than 'classic' MVC where the View can read from the Model. "Unlike most MVC-style configurations, Passive View results in no dependencies between view and model."

Answer (score 0):

Split main applogic on several small MVC "widgets"(controllers), where every "widget" has own relation to Model and own separate View. Then, during execution aplication you can just execute widgets in runtime, and pass to main template "READY widget views".

Something like that is described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control

advantages:

- you dont break MVC (at least so much)
  IMO, its much better than call Model from
  view)
- keep structured not only the
  codebase by usually applogic/use cases
  described in stanalone widgets (where each has own template)
- small widgets
  more easy to test

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about speed performance of your app, and you want to make it more straightforward, I would say you allow views to read data from the model (read only). It is more complicated when both controllers and view must be in sync re. data that views need and controllers should provide to views. And when views can access model directly, you don't need to verify that controllers provide this data.

In regards to the argument that MVC concept is based on loose coupling, there is no contradiction as Model is still independent and does not rely on views or controllers. And the difference between controllers and views are that controllers can both push and pull to (from) the model, and views can only pull from the model.